# change which psql launches on startup

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed brew install postgresql , which was fine and worked well.

I then installed  brew install postgresql8 as I wanted to check some postgres 8 specific things.

I then uninstalled postgresql8, however when I restart my mac, and run which psql, it still defaults to

```
  /opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/psql
```

How can I change this back to default to the latest 9.x psql?

Answer (score 0):

The executable which launches is dependent on PATH-variable and which-command makes its checks based on that variable also. The contents of the PATH-variable depend on different things. You can find more info [in here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) for example.

You can launch the right psql by writing the full path on the command line, for example:

```
~$ /opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/psql
```